# Laravel: what is storage key in auth.php?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

From [API Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication), it says

> If you choose to use a different column name, be sure to update your API's `storage_key` configuration option within the `config/auth.php` configuration file.

I use `token` column instead if `api_token` name which is the default one for Laravel API authentication. It says config `storage_key` to use a different name. I can't find such thing and Googling this didn't say anything. What is   `storage_key` and how can I use this to set the `token` as API authentication column name not `api_token`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the method inside `Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager`

```
/**
 * Create a token based authentication guard.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  array  $config
 * @return \Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard
 */
public function createTokenDriver($name, $config)
{
    // The token guard implements a basic API token based guard implementation
    // that takes an API token field from the request and matches it to the
    // user in the database or another persistence layer where users are.
    $guard = new TokenGuard(
        $this->createUserProvider($config['provider'] ?? null),
        $this->app['request'],
        $config['input_key'] ?? 'api_token',
        $config['storage_key'] ?? 'api_token'
    );

    $this->app->refresh('request', $guard, 'setRequest');

    return $guard;
}
```

it's on the same level with `provider`, also as it can be seen from the class it is in the same level with `driver`. you need to put `storage_key` and `input_key` inside one of the selected `guards`(`api` for example) that you will use for authentication. By default, they are both set to `api_token`.

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Thanks, hence can I have some thing like this

    'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'storage_key' => 'token'
        ],

Comment: That's right @MamaD, you may also append  `input_key` to overwrite default value `api_token`.